# How to set size to CircularProgressIndicator?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a loading screen for my application, I'm using `CircularProgressIndicator` widget, but I want to know if there's a way to make it bigger in height and width, it's too small.

So, could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 270, accepted):

You can wrap your `CircularProgressIndicator` inside a `Center` and then `SizedBox` to define the size:

```dart
       @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    child: Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator()
                    ),
                    height: 200.0,
                    width: 200.0,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    child: Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator()
                    ),
                    height: 50.0,
                    width: 50.0,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    child: Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator()
                    ),
                    height: 10.0,
                    width: 10.0,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
```

Comment: Doing that, the circle is not correctly displayed and is cropped with Box dimensions.

Comment: Make sure your child is Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()) or the indicator will not fit the size box.

Comment: @AndresCastro do you have any idea why the progress indicator has to be inside a Center widget?

Comment: could be in Center or Align , but it should have a parent with constraints

Comment: @diegoveloper I tried SizedBox with width/height, but the progress indicator still got out of the parent.

Comment: add Center or Align as a parent of your SizedBox

Comment: @diegoveloper, may I ask you to have a look at a Flutter related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60565658/fluter-image-picker-package-show-images-one-after-another-with-delete-action ?

Comment: Instead of Center or Align one may use an UnconstrainedBox (see https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints)

Comment: Thanks @AndresCastro for the Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()), still true in 2023.

Comment: On the contrary, @LexonLi, I found Andres' answer still made the circle oval-shaped. What solved it for me was wrapping the parent SizedBox in a Center, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59030730/2063246.

Answer (score 88):

Please test your answers.

By simply placing the CircularProgressIndicator in a SizedBox, or a Container:

```
main() =>
    runApp(
        SizedBox(width: 30, height: 30, child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
```

... still results in the CircularProgressIndicator filling the available space. SizedBox does not constrain the CircularProgressIndicator (which seems like a bug in Flutter).

Wrapping it with Center, however, will make it work:

```
main() =>
    runApp(Center(child: 
        SizedBox( width: 30, height: 30, child: CircularProgressIndicator())));
```

I complained about this confusing behavior on Github. The flutter team helpfully responded with new docs explaining that a widget’s desired size may be ignored for if it’s alignment can’t be determined.

https://github.com/flutter/website/pull/5010/commits/3070c777a61b493b46cdde92fa7afc21de7adf25

Comment: It doesn't @AshwinBalani. Atleast did not work in my case, so can safely conclude that your assumption is not correct.

Comment: Again -- its not about SizedBox or Container, and the accepted answer is incorrect. Without an alignment, the sizes of those widgets are ignored.
Flutter *finally* added a note about it. https://github.com/flutter/website/issues/4992#event-4033238437

Comment: @rahulserver can you share your code buddy? May be I can help

Answer (score 79):

Simple is always powerful, wrap it with transform widget

```
Transform.scale(
  scale: 0.5,
  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
)
```

Comment: This works. Other solutions result in an oval instead of a circle.

Comment: This works good. Other Solution may or may not work depend on your Widget Tree/Parent Widgets.

Comment: this should be the most voted answer because `transform` maintain the position of the widget while center widget does not maintain the constraint width and height

Answer (score 31):

You can control the size of the indicator better if you wrap it with a `Column` Widget. It doesn't hurt, but gets the job done. In my case is was using a **small loading indicator inside a button.**

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    Center(
      child: Container(
        height: 20,
        width: 20,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          strokeWidth: 2.0,
          valueColor : AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: Yes that worked for me, too! And if you want to have a minimal dialog in terms of height, just give the column this additional attribute:   mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min

Answer (score 17):

This is the solution, which worked for me

```
Center(
        heightFactor: 1,
        widthFactor: 1,
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 16,
          width: 16,
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            strokeWidth: 1.5,
          ),
        ),
      )
```

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me. The important thing was wrapping a center around the progress indicator

```
SizedBox(
  height: 16,
  width: 16,
  child: Center(
   child: CircularProgressIndicator(
    strokeWidth: 1.5,
   )
  )
),
```

Answer (score 5):

This could be useful

```
Container(
          width: 50.0,
          height: 20.0,
          child: (CircularProgressIndicator(
            valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
              Colors.green,
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            value: 0.2,
          ))),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this example to handle better the widget Indicator display.

```
SizedBox(
        height: 15.0,
        width: 15.0,
            child: Transform.scale(
              scale: 2,
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                strokeWidth: 2,
                    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                      Color(Colors.blue),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

This will allow you change the size of the indicator and control it better inside a box or button.

Answer (score 2):

Add alignment property inside the Container

```
Container(
       alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
       child:CircularProgressIndicator()
    ),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could prevent the `CircularProgressIndicator` from being clipped at the top, bottom, left and right was by wrapping it in a `Padding` with padding set to half the stroke width of the indicator.

```
  Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
    child: SizedBox(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
        strokeWidth: 10,
      )
    )
  )
```

Not sure why this was suddenly an issue though, I've been using circular progress indicators for years with no problems before.

Answer (score 0):

You should give the Container or SizedBox the same width as the height. CircularProgressIndicator will become an ellipse if the width and height are different.

The container is only preferable when you want some customization with resizing.

```
 const SizedBox(
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                color: Colors.blue,
                strokeWidth: 10,
              ),
            ),
```

or

```
   const Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.amber),
      child: const CircularProgressIndicator(
        color: Colors.red,
        strokeWidth: 20,
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const SizedBox(
      height: 16,
      width: 16,
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
        strokeWidth: 1.5,
      ),
    ),
```

you also set color for CircularProgressIndicator and some other properties as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know, it's about `flutter`, but native topics are not found and I don't want to create a question for every solution found.

In `Compose`:

```
CircularProgressIndicator(
    modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp)
        .requiredSize(20.dp)
)
```

I see that 2 answers got minuses for native solutions. You should know that Android `native` questions also receive `flutter` answers.

Answer (score -1):

```
bool isLoading = false;

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return isLoading
    ? _loadingIndicator()
    : FlatButton.icon(
    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
    label: Text('Go to'),
    onPressed: () async {
      setState(() => isLoading = true);
      // Async code ---> Then
      setState(() => isLoading = false);
    },
  );
}

Widget _loadingIndicator() {
  return Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0),
    child: SizedBox(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue),
        strokeWidth: 3.0,
      ),
      height: 25.0,
      width: 25.0,
    ),
  ) ;
}
```

Comment: Please give some description about your answer.

Answer (score -1):

This easiest way for me.

```
CircularProgressIndicator(
    color = AppForeGroundColor,
    strokeWidth = 3.dp, // --> Circle stroke size
    modifier = Modifier.size(16.dp) // --> Width/Height
)
```

Comment: The question was about Flutter, not Compose.