# Flutter Progress Indicator Size

Tags: widget, progress-bar, flutter

I was wondering if there was a way to change the width/length/height of both the linear and circular progress bar. I'm trying to make a XP bar using it, but I'm not sure if that's possible. Also, I am aware the values are only through 0.0 and 1.0, but I also think it's possible(not sure) that I would be able to make a formula to where it will still work.

Comment: could you put the code you have? You'll have to change the constraints of the parents of the Linear/Circular progress indicator, you can change the height , width , and the value is from 0.0 to 1.0.

Answer (score 38):

Progress indicator will fill its parent layout widget e.g

```
SizedBox(
    height: 300.0,
    width: 300.0,
    child: 
        CircularProgressIndicator(
        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.blue),
        strokeWidth: 5.0)
    )
```

Comment: SizedBox does not constrain the shape of the CircularProgressIndicator. It seems like a bug in Flutter. Wrapping it all in `Center(child: )`, however, does.

Comment: This is the code I have used in production, if it's not working now it would appear then that something has changed in the latest version of Flutter. Hopefully it is just a bug, what build channel are you using? (stable, beta, dev, master?)

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51901379/how-to-set-size-to-circularprogressindicator/60049283#60049283
Whether the SizeBox has any effect seems to depend on what it is contained in (works as advertized if contained in a Center, for example, but not within a Stack).
I've submitted a bug: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50075

Comment: A SizedBox is constrained (size enforced) by its parent and won't loosen those constraints (Center will loosen constraints).  If constraints are "tight" (no size variation allowed) at screen width (e.g. inside a vertical scroll ListView), SizedBox width argument will be ignored.  Wrapping SizedBox in Center works as Center fills the largest space possible and then loosens constraints for its child, allowing child to take any size it wants. https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints section "Tight vs. loose constraints" explains this a bit

Answer (score 9):

1. With this code you decide that it is an array of Widget,
   if you put that is an array,
   it's because of the response you can give,
   You can have more widget to add,
2. That is centered
3. and what is a CircularProgressIndicator.

In this way, the Circular Progress Indicator
will not take the width and height of the father that contains it

regards

`<Widget>[Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())]`

Answer (score 1):

How can I combine a class that creates a loading indicator with my
button, so that when I press it, the indicator turns on and flips to
the next page?

Here the code:

```
class Loader extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State createState() => LoaderState();
    }

    class LoaderState extends State<Loader> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
      AnimationController controller;
      Animation<double> animation;

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        controller = AnimationController(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1200), vsync: this);
        animation = CurvedAnimation(parent: controller, curve: Curves.elasticOut);
        animation.addListener(() {
          this.setState(() {});
        });
        animation.addStatusListener((AnimationStatus status) {});
        controller.repeat();
      }

      @override
      void dispose() {
        controller.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              height: 3.0,
              width: animation.value * 100.0,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue[300],
              height: 3.0,
              width: animation.value * 75.0,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              height: 3.0,
              width: animation.value * 50.0,
            )
          ],
        );
      }
    }


    Expanded(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding:
                              EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 5.0, top:20.0),
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => FirstScreen()));
                            },
                            child: Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                height: 45.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Color(0xFF1976D2),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9.0)),
                                child: Text('Login',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white))),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

Comment: How can I combine a class that creates a loading indicator with my button, so that when I press it, the indicator turns on and flips to the next page ?

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer

Comment: By clicking on the Login button, the loading indicator should appear for 3 seconds, and then go to the next page.