# How to fix CircularProgressIndicator() size in toolbar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to set fixed size CircularProgressIndicator in toolbar actions[] but it is giving me the inappropriate size,
the code I am using,

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(Lang.postDetails),
        actions: <Widget>[
       Container(

                  width: 16,
                  height: 16,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                )
```

and output I am getting,

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have solved this myself,
If anyone faces this issue just wrap your `Container` inside a `Center` widget,

```
Center(
       child: Container(
       width: 16,
       height: 16,
       child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
       )
```

Output

[image]

Comment: or use SizedBox Widget

Comment: Yes, use any of SizeBox or Container but Center widget is the key.