# SizedBox() not increasing size of CircularProgressIndicator()

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, sized-box

I was having issues increasing the size of my circular progress indicator and after doing some research I landed on this Stack Overflow question: [How to set size to CircularProgressIndicator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51901379/how-to-set-size-to-circularprogressindicator)

So I wrapped my item in a SizedBox() and increased the height and width and nothing changed.

I Also tried adding an expanded to the circular progress indicator but that didnt work either:

```
                    return Expanded(
                      child: PageView(
                        controller: pageViewController,
                        children: [
                          PackSummaryWeightGraph(
                              categoryWeightList: categoryWeightList,
                              totalWeight: totalWeight),
                          Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 40,
                                width: 40,
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                  value: packedItemsPercent,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          const Center(
                            child: Text('Third Page'),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
```

**Edit**:

IS there anyway to do this programmatically so I do not need to set the size of the width and height manually? I just want it to fill the space.

Comment: You seem to be a little confused about the basic layout concepts in flutter, take a read here: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints

Answer (score 1):

It needs a parent with constraint, try to wrap it inside a Center or Align

```
Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 40,
            width: 40,
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              value: packedItemsPercent,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the `CircularProgessIndicator` in a `FittedBox` like so:

```
SizedBox(
    height: 40,
    width: 40,
    child: FittedBox(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
        value: packedItemsPercent,
      ),
    ),
  )
```

Comment: actually going to edit this issue the sized box did work without the fitted box, but I dont know how to make it will the area instead of setting the hight and width manually